# Hartl Rails Tutorial Exercise 2 (Chapter 10.1.1) re: partial for sign-up and update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Exercise 2 of Hartl's [Rails Tutorial chapter 10.1.1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users) asks to DRY out the 'new' and 'edit' views by creating a partial for the user form. As described in the exercise, an earlier exercised resulted in a discrepancy that I need to address in the partial. I am hoping this will be an easy fix. Here's my code:

This is the form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Drying out this edit.html.erb as such, using the form partial works fine:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Edit user') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Save changes') %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">Change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my new.html.erb view, which should render the form partial to replace the form. The discrepancy is in the beginning of the form, where the parameters for form_for include "@user" AND "**url: signup_path**" :

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, the improved, DRYed out view should be something like this, with some tweaks to handle the discrepancy.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create my account') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Back to the question: How can I edit the form partial to handle this discrepancy? Many thanks for reading and helping out this rails newbie!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `new_record?` method.

So your `form_for` would look like this:

```
<%= form_for( @user, url: @user.new_record? ? signup_path : user_update_path %>
```

[Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F) are the docs for `new_record?`.

I like to use new record for simple things like changing button text in the view. Here's an example:

```
<%= submit_tag(object.new_record? ? 'Update' : 'Create' , class: 'nice') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pass in a [local variable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) to the partial:

```
<%= render 'form', url: signup_path %>
```

Then in the form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: url) do |f| %>
```

You can now pass in different paths for the form on a per-render basis.

Comment: Your solution works for the 'new' view, but now since the 'edit' view doesn't have a url, an error results when trying to render the 'edit' view.

I'm not sure if this is the correct convention, but could this be solved by adding "patch  '/update',   to: 'users#update'" to routes.rb and then, in edit.html.erb, passing url: update_path to the render method? This appears to work, but there is likely an easier way to handle this. Thanks.

Comment: If you're planning on your user's update form to hit a separate endpoint then you will need a route and corresponding controller action to handle the update.